# Can not add ripple effect on TextView using foreground selectableItemBackground

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button

I tried to add ripple effect on my TextView used as button which has dark background.

I already tried

1. `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on TextView
2. `android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"` on TextView parent becuase Textview has dark background, also tried light theme.

Also i can not set TextView background as `android:background="attr/selectableItemBackground` because i need some dark background on textview.

Can someone give me understanding, how can i achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Dark theme.  Ripple color is not being visible on dark . So you should try to use a Custom theme with .

```
  <style name="TextViewTheme" parent="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Add this theme for TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="Android"
    android:theme="@style/TextViewTheme"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textSize="23sp"/>
```

Comment: Dude still cant see ripple effect

Comment: Have you put Click listener ? Cause i have tested it and it works .

Comment: Yes i use this textview as button

Comment: By the way it works when i put selectableitembackground as background of textview, but in that case i cant set my custom background color

Comment: It will work for `Button` also . Read the answer. I did not put  `selectableitembackground` as `background` i used a color as background .

Comment: Dude i am using textview not button, i tried this way before you answer, and tried once more after you answered but it does not work, my textview has red background.

Comment: And whats the color of `colorControlHighlight` in Style ?

Comment: Its tested . Something wrong with your approach . See if `TextView` Onclick is working or not . Also add the style Entry in **v-21**

Comment: My app is completed, so all clicks are working, i was just adding some effects in app, so i needed to do this. Also i dont think selectableItemBackground needs to be override in v-21, just ripple attributes are needed to do so.

Comment: I ended up with using an parentview with red background and to use selectableItemBackground as background of textview.

Comment: `selectableItemBackground` not need to be. `colorControlHighlight` is .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168490/discussion-between-khemraj-and-adm).

Answer (score 0):

One can use `MaterialButton` like this to have ripple effect on click.

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/padding_8dp"
        android:text="Clickable Text"
        android:textColor="your text color"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        app:rippleColor="ripple effect color" />
```